# Mylyn Task Focus UI

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

If you use the **Mylyn** task focus UI, the package explorer shows

```
sourceFolder/package/fileName/classTypeName/methodName
```

for any class in the context of an  active task. Is it possible to remove `classTypeName` and `methodName` and show only all entities up to their fileName?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't generally need the structure inside the Java file, so I just disable that in the Package Explorer completely. To do that:

- go to the View menu (the little triangle)
- choose "Filters"
- check "Java Members"

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in Project Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for this handy tip, those expanded class innards really got on my nerves! One addition: I had to uncheck the package explorer's Mylyn button ("Focus on active tasks") to be able to edit the filters (Eclipse Indigo). Afterwards I could re-enable it.

Answer (score 2):

You can uncheck "Window -> Preferences -> Mylyn -> Context -> Auto expand tree views when focused", this may help to some extend.

Answer (score 0):

On Eclipse PDT I used Navigator View instead of PHP Explorer View:

- Window -> Show View -> Navigator

That way only the filenames are displayed. 
After that i added filters to exclude files from view, e.g. .* resources.